# How to calculate multiple rows on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I Have a table that looks something like this:

```
ComputerID | Free_Space | Disk_Size
------------------------------------------
Computer1  | 10         | 15
Computer1  | 10         | 10
Computer1  | 05         | 10
Computer2  | 05         | 05
Computer2  | 05         | 10
Computer3  | 11         | 15
Computer3  | 04         | 05
```

I need to achieve something like this:

```
ComputerID | Free_Space | Disk_Size
------------------------------------------
Computer1  | 25         | 35
Computer2  | 10         | 15
Computer3  | 15         | 20
```

I've tried something like this but with no success.

```
 SELECT ComputerID,
 SUM(free_space/1000000000) AS 'Total Free Space',
 SUM(disk_size/1000000000) AS 'Total Size'
 FROM myTable
 ORDER BY ComputerID
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Replace `order by` with `group by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT
    ComputerID,
    SUM(free_space/1000000000) AS "Total Free Space",
    SUM(disk_size/1000000000) AS "Total Size"
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY
    ComputerID
ORDER BY
    ComputerID
```

Note also that most SQL dialects use the single quotes as string delimiters and double quotes as delimiters for column names. With SQL Server you can also used square brackets

`[Total Free Space]`.

Comment: That worked perfect, just one last question: how can I include a CASE statement within a SELECT DISTINCT clause. What I'm trying to do is if the disk size is less than a GB it will give the the total in MB, if is less than a TB give the total in GB otherwise it will give me the total in TB.  I hope that made sense.

Comment: I would return plain bytes from the query and do this kind of logic in the application. With CASE it would work like this: `CASE WHEN free_space < 1000 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, free_space) + ' Bytes' WHEN free_space < 1000000 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, free_space/1000) + ' KB' WHEN ... ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, free_space/1000000000000) + ' TB'  END`

Comment: @Oliver SELECT DISTINCT
  d.name as Name,
  CASE WHEN dk.size < 1000000000 THEN SUM (cast(dk.size/1000000000 as text))||'GB'
  ELSE
    SUM (cast(dk.size/1000000000000 as text))||'GB'
  END

FROM devices d
  
JOIN disks dk ON dk.computer_id = d.id
 
WHERE
  ROUND(dk.size/1073741824.0,1) > 0
  AND
    d.type = 'Computer'
   
GROUP BY d.name

Comment: I would say, either use DISTINCT or, in this case, GROUP BY, but both together?

Comment: Using powers of 2 is probably more appropriate, POWER(2,10) = 1KB, POWER(2,20) = MB, POWER(2,30) = 1GB, POWER(2,40) = 1TB.

Comment: SORRY IGNORE THE COMMENT ABOVE. Hi Oliver I've tried what you said above but it didn't work unless a didn't put them in the right way. I'm including a sample of my report:                                                                                                                               SELECT DISTINCT
  d.name as Name,
  SUM(CAST(dk.size/1000000000 AS text)) as "Disk Size (GB)"
  
FROM devices d
  
GROUP BY d.name

Comment: SQL is not my field, you right I'm just using the GROUP BY now.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ComputerID,
SUM(free_space/1000000000) AS 'Total Free Space',
SUM(disk_size/1000000000) AS 'Total Size'
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ComputerID
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you now put on the question, simply do this:

```
SELECT ComputerID,
SUM(free_space) AS 'Total Free Space',
SUM(disk_size) AS 'Total Size'

FROM myTable

GROUP BY ComputerID
```

---

If the values are in bytes and you want to display them in gb do is like this:

```
SELECT ComputerID,
SUM(free_space/1073741824) AS 'Total Free Space',
SUM(disk_size/1073741824) AS 'Total Size'

FROM myTable

GROUP BY ComputerID
```

Comment: That worked but still having problems in the calculation, is not calculation properly. e.g. Computer1 should be 76.7 (that's in GB) but it appears 155419. any clue why?

Comment: Coloca então os dados que tens de input na tua questão (faz um select *), para eu testar melhor.

Comment: Put the input data on yout question (with a select *) and I'll tell you why.

Comment: @NunoMarques to achieve what you put on the question you don't need the division. Simply do this. If the size is on bytes and you want gb make the division by 1024 three times or by 1073741824 one time.

Answer (score 1):

Any query using aggregate functions (e.g. sum()) mixed with non-aggregated fields (computerid) must use a group by clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY ComputerID
ORDER BY ...
```